# Getting xml string data from element using XmlPullParser

Tags: android, android-xml, xmlpullparser

for example I have xml file:

```
 <names>
        <item value="Hello" />
        <item value="All" />
        <item value="This" />
        <item value="Data" />
 </names>
```

So I need to get all raw data from the given attribute (names):

```
    <item value="Hello" />
    <item value="All" />
    <item value="This" />
    <item value="Data" />
```

In a string format, so the data should be:

```
String data = "
<item value="Hello" />
<item value="All" />
<item value="This" />
<item value="Data" />
";
```

and I have a peace of code:

```
 int state = 0;
    do {
        try {
            state = parser.next();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }       
        if (state == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            if (parser.getName().equals("names")) {

// here I need to get the data
// String data = ...

               break;
            }
        }
    } while(state != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT);
```

so, how do I get data from xml element in string format?

Answer (score 3):

I used [DOM2XmlPullBuilder](http://www.extreme.indiana.edu/xmlpull-website/v1/addons/java/dom2_builder/src/org/xmlpull/v1/dom2_builder/DOM2XmlPullBuilder.java) to convert XmlPullParser to a DOM, then convert the DOM to a string. The code looks something like this.

```
DOM2XmlPullBuilder dom2XmlPullBuilder = new DOM2XmlPullBuilder();
Element element = dom2XmlPullBuilder.parseSubTree(xmlPullParser);
convertNodeToString(element); // implement using a Transformer
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe instead of where you have

```
if (parser.getName().equals("names")) {...
```

it should be something like this:

```
ArrayList<String> data=new ArrayList<String>();
....
....
if (parser.getName().equals("item")) {
   data.add(xpp.getAttributeValue(0));
}
```

I'm a beginner so I was just searching this information recently, luckily I found a helpful sample from commonsguy (which copied and ran fine without any change) - https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Resources/XML